# Objective-c count all the instances of a certain class

Tags: objective-c, class, count, instance

Hi let's say i have a class "car" and a class "cardatabase".
in the cardatabase file i create a NSMutableArray where i store all the instances and i can easily count them.

but what if i want to count the instances within the car class itself? something like creating a class method +(int)count ?

```
+(int)count
```

how should i do?

Comment: It is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17850971/1226304

Answer (score -1):

Check out this:
This clearly implies the way to count object instances by implementing class methods.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_Objective-C_Class_Methods

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score -2):

-----------------Car.h----------------------------

```
Car : NSObject
{
}

@property(nonatomic,strong) CarDatabase database; 

-(int)count;
```

-------------------- Car.m--------------

```
-(int)count{
  return database.arrayYouDefined.count;
}
```

Comment: sorry i probably didn't explain good. I know how to count elements of an array. what i need to know is if there is a way to count all the instances active of a certain class