# Get number of instances of custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, instance, counter, multiple-instances

I have created a custom class in xcode: `PaperPack` and defined 2 instant variables: `title` and `author`-

Then I alloc 2 instances of the class as below:

```
PaperPack *pack1 = [[PaperPack alloc] init];
pack1.title = @"Title 1";
pack1.author = @"Author";

PaperPack *pack2 = [[PaperPack alloc] init];
pack1.title = @"Title 2";
pack1.author = @"Author";
```

Then how do I count and return number of instances I have created with that class?

Comment: @Wain i need to pass the number to a different class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not get directly. Whenever you create in instance add it any Array and then access it using that array properties.

**Ex :**

```
NSMutableArray *allInstancesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
PaperPack *pack1 = [[PaperPack alloc] init];
pack1.title = @"Title 1";
pack1.author = @"Author";
    [allInstancesArray addObject:pack1];

PaperPack *pack2 = [[PaperPack alloc] init];
pack1.title = @"Title 2";
pack1.author = @"Author";
    [allInstancesArray addObject:pack2];
```

Then get count as :

```
NSLog(@"TOTAL INSTANCES : %d",[allInstancesArray count]);
```

Comment: It could be better in his case (if he only need the number of instances) to keep an int instance, for example, instead of a NSMutableArray. Like @Wain solution.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a factory singleton which you use to count the number of instances requested (then you must create all instances using the factory). Or you could add a `static` variable into the `PaperPack` class and increment it each time (in the `init` method, then you must call `init` each time).

Comment: +1, if you need just a number... count... You shouldn't have array of instanses

Comment: Singleton...best practices at its best

Answer (score 0):

```
static PaperPack *_paperPack;

@interface PaperPack ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger createdCount;

- (PaperPack *)sharedPaperPack;

@end

@implementation PaperPack

+ (PaperPack *)sharedPaperPack
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {       
        if(!_sharedPaperPack)
        {

             _sharedPaperPack = [[[self class] alloc] init];

        }
    }
    return _sharedPaperPack;
}

+ (PaperPack*)paperPack {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [PaperPack sharedPaperPack].createdCount ++;
    }
    return self;
}
```

To use it:

Just call class method which will increase "createdCount" value

```
PaperPack *firstPaperPack = [PaperPack paperPack];
PaperPack *secondPaperPack = [PaperPack paperPack];
```

and to count:

```
NSInteger count = [PaperPack sharedPaperPack].createdCount;
```

Sorry if something is incorrect, code is written from memory

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following
**Method 1**

```
// PaperPack.h
@interface PaperPack : NSObject
+ (int)count;
@end

// PaperPack.m
static int theCount = 0;

@implementation PaperPack
-(id)init
{
  if([super init])
   {
     count = count + 1 ; 
   }
  return self ;
}
+ (int) count
 { 
   return theCount; 
  }
@end
```

when you want the number of objects created

```
[PaperPack count];
```

**Method 2**

1)add a property to your class `PaperPack.h`

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger count ;
```

2)synthesize it in `PaperPack.m`

```
@synthesize count ;
```

3) modify `init` method

```
-(id)init
{
  if([super init])
   {
     self = [super init] ;
     self.count = self.count + 1 ; 
   }
   return self ;
}
```

4)when you want the number of objects created

```
  NSLog(@"%d",pack1.count);
   NSLOg(@"%d",pack2.count);
```